# Django templates relative path

Tags: python, django, templates

```
import os.path

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
   #os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),
)
```

I want to know what exactly the TEMPLATE_DIRS is , so i run it on the Django shell,

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.dirname(__file__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

Why such kind of legal attribute failed in shell? I did do some test in shell and came another question:

```
>>> os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname('/user/name'))
'/'
>>> os.path.dirname('/user/name')
'/user'
>>> B = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname('/user/name'))
>>> os.path.join(B,'template')
'/template'
```

The code with comment, `os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')`, doesn't it come out with `'/templates'`? 
Isn't that a root directory? If that, how can Django search my templates files in a directory that even i don't have it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `__file__` doesn't exist in a Python shell. So you can't just test the value like that.

The `BASE_DIR` value will be equal the parent folder of the file where the line is situation. If you have a Django project and the line is in `/home/xyz/foo/foo/settings.py`, then `BASE_DIR` is equal to `/home/xyz/foo`.

**Why?** `__file__` returns the absolute path of the current file, here, our `settings.py`. After, you are taking two times the folder. The first time it will take `/home/xyz/foo/foo/` (it removes the file name in the path) and the second time it will take the **parent** folder. Hence, we arrive to the project main folder.

Also, you don't need to replace `\\` by `/` since the Python `os.path` module know how to deal with this according to your current OS.

In summary, your current line point to a `templates/` directory at the root of your Django project :)

Comment: I just want to test both way to create TEMPLATE_DIRS . It seems that "os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')" doesn't work, why?

Comment: Have you notice the experiment i test there? <br/> >>> os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname('/user/name'))
'/'<br/> It gives me only a slash after me taking two times the folder. So how can BASE_DIR is equal to /home/xyz/foo if i have django project in /home/xyz/foo/foo/settings.py? I mean BASE_DIR will be '/', am i on the point?

Comment: It won't work this only on `os.path.dirname` because it will search in `/home/xyz/foo/foo/templates` which doesn't exist. You forgot one `dirname` before calling `os.path.join`.
I don't see any problems in your tests with `dirname`: at each call it removes one folder from the path.

Comment: ohhh, I see, i mixed up something. Thank you